# Not showing as a contributor on GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm struggling to get GitHub to show my contributions to a project. It is not my repository, but other repositories I've contributed to do show up on my profile.

I've tested contributions to both shared and private repositories work. I've pushed from other projects and everything is working as expected. The patches from the non-working project and a working one, both show the same details. Any pushes to working projects show me as a contributor on both the repository and my personal profile.

`git config --global user.email` and `git config --global user.name` are both correct. The repository I am committing to shows me as the author, but not on my profile.

I'm a bit lost on what to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/contact)

Comment: you can refer [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Few things might lead to you not being able to see your own contributions to another person's git repository.

1. The owner of the repository may not have merged your branch yet, if so, you may not show up as a contributor because technically at that point in time, you still have no code in that master branch.
2. Your pull request was not opened and is sitting stagnant. Note that even if some did open your branches pull request, because of the reason above, you may not see yourself as a contributor still until they merged you.
3. Your branch was opened and closed without merging. Your code was not added to the master branch therefore you did not technically contribute.
4. The owners repository is private and he or she chooses not to share their private contributions. Because of this you are not able to share your contributions to their private repository either.
5. Commit rollback. Although I am not certain of this, perhaps if they rolled back past a commit that included your code, you may not show up. Once again, I am not certain of this.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Mine is still not showing one of the contributors that have assisted me. Any ideas? It is public and I merged their request right now. Does it take time? Any other ideas?

Comment: @TalC i am facing exact same problem

Comment: Not showing for me either. It seems like a broken feature.

Comment: Same problem here, linked email, PR merged in, still not showing as a contributor

Answer (score 40):

Github shows only the top 100 contributors for a project.

If there are more than 100, the other contributors beyond these top 100 are never shown.

Even if you set a date range and there are less than 100 contributors displayed for the selected period, the list still only contains contributors who are among the all-time top 100.

Comment: that's what happened with me, I wasn't in top 100 contributors.
https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.8/user/articles/i-don-t-see-myself-in-the-repository-contributors-graph

Comment: I vaguely thought that they might even filter out top 100 in period view, but I'm not sure. This is way harder then....

Comment: This is what I want to know. Contributors does not really show "top 100 contributors" when I set a range of time.

Answer (score 38):

Sometime if you do fork, commit or merge in your branch, it still doesn't show your name in contributors. It may be due to email which you set on command line is not mentioned in your git profile. Following steps work for me.

1. go to https://github.com/settings/emails
2. Add your email to 'add Email address' option which is used on command line

Now check the contributors tab on project. It will start showing your contributions.

Comment: My username was showing up as disabled, even when my account was active. Vinayak's answer helped me figure that my config email was different from the one from the one showing in Github account's settings. Added the config email, and everything was normal. Thanks.

Comment: This caused my commits to appear associated with my account, where they weren't before, but I still don't show up on the contributors page. Maybe it just takes some time to refresh…

Answer (score 18):

Setting your email address for every repository on your computer

```
git config --global user.email "your_git_email@email.com"
```

OR setting your email address for a single repository

```sh
git config user.email "your_git_email@email.com"
```

Then commit something and check contributors tab.

Read more from [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/)

Answer (score 6):

If the repo has more than 100 contributors your name won't appear but you can use the Github API to understand how far in the list you are to be one of the top 100 contributors.

Check the [Github API documentation](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.8/v3/repos/#list-contributors).

GET `/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors`

Play with the `page` param to found yourself.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors?page=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out Github's help on contributions: [link](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)

In particular, if the repository you are contributing to is forked from another repository, or if they are merged into a non-default branch, they will not be counted on your profile.

If they were commits to a pull request someone else opened, it is also possible that the maintainers squashed the commits, and then only the one who opened the pull request gets credit.

Answer (score 2):

Another overlooked reason might be: ***commit was made less than 24 hours ago.***

After making a commit that meets the requirements to count as a contribution, you may need to wait for up to 24 hours to see the contribution appear on your contributions graph.

Reference: [Common reasons that contributions are not counted](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted)